# Qt6 integration of 3dconnexion spacemouse devices

Tags: qt, integration, vtk, hid

hope this finds you well.

I have been wondering if there are any updates regarding qt integration of the spacemouse sdk.

I found this old post https://forum.3dconnexion.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=4968 but all the source code files are not present anymore and I don't think I'm skilled enough to rewrite it given the information present in the forum (here's the updated link to the post https://www.codegardening.com/post/2011/2011-02-05-using-the-3dconnexion-mouse-with-a-qt-application/) and honestly it looks strange to me that Qt has not yet made any integration packages for 3d connexion devices.

I am using Visual Studio 16 on a Windows machine in a Qt6 VTK9.2 OpenCV project

I have tried the basic windows way using window handlers but I can't make it work (no input read) as soon as I pass the handler to the qMainWindow as HWND(mainWindow.winId()), while it works fine if I create a dedicated window to read the data.

Could you please give me some suggestions or point me to some resources?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to implement SpaceMouse integration using the official [SDK](https://3dconnexion.com/uk/software-developer-program/) (registration required) and using [this](https://github.com/Kitware/ParaView/tree/master/Plugins/SpaceMouseInteractor) example from a Qt-based application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there a small code sample you could provide showing (a part of) the functionality? Examples elsewhere on the web sometimes don't last as long as StackOverflow questions.